# Why the "xAxis.minorSplitLine" doesn't work after setting `xAxis.data` in echarts

Tags: echarts

If `xAxis.data` be setted, like:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400], 
    minorSplitLine: {
      show: true
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [1.2, 1.44, 1.72, 2.07, 2.49, 2.98, 3.58, 4.3, 5.16]
    }
  ]
};
```

The minor split line will be not show:

[image]

When I delete `xAxis.data`, everything will works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your data (x and y) in `series` instead.

```js
option = {
  xAxis: { 
    minorSplitLine: {
      show: true
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [[0, 1.2], [50, 1.44], [100, 1.72], [150, 2.07], [200, 2.49], [250, 2.98], [300, 3.58], [350, 4.3], [400, 5.16]]
    }
  ]
};
```

[image]

That's because when you set `xAxis` `data`, you implicitly make it a `'category'` `type`, while what you want here is a `'value'` type (which is implicitly done with my code).

If the type is set to `'category'`, the splitLine does not make sense since a point is in a category or isn't, it's not made for continuous numerical data (this is what `'value'` type is made for).